# How to use bundle from adapter to other class?

Tags: android

My case is to use data from an adapter to activity class.
code can be-

```
Intent in = new Intent(context, TargetActivity.class);
getIntent().putExtra("mykey", myVariable);
startActivity(in);
```

But I don't want the TargetActivity to be opened at that event. just need to pass the value.

Tried this too-

```
     Bundle b = new Bundle();
     b.putString("mykey", ""+myvariable);
     Obj.setArguments(b);
```

I used the above in case of passing data from activity to fragment using target fragment_obj.
But how to achieve that (adapter to activity). Help me out.

Here is my code from onBindViewHolder of RecyclerView adaptor

```
 @Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    final MyQues mq = qdatalist.get(position);
    holder.tv_qid.setText(mq.getqNo()+"");
    holder.tv_quesOnList.setText(mq.getQues());

    String quesNum = mq.getqNo()+"";
```

Now what I want next is to send the value of String quesNum to other activity from where I have to read some data from firebase using that key.
I can't take it from database-model there, as the firebase key is further being generated using that key based on the position only. Thus I have to use the same to read which changes according to position.

Thus attempting to send it to other activity where I will use it as the key to read data from firebase.

Comment: Please explain your problem in detail. Also mention the code of adapter and class. If you want to send data from adapter to activity and you want activity should not be launched than you have to persist the state of object in a file, shared preferences or in a database.

Comment: I have edited the post. Take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.. I did that @Raj, & got the value at MainActivity but while sending it again to other activity I am getting null pointer exception there. here is the code:

MainActivity

```
@Override  public void onClick(String quesNum) {
//Toast.makeText(this, ""+quesNum, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserResponseListActivity.class);  
 getIntent().putExtra("quesNum",""+quesNum);  
 startActivity(in);
```

On other activity:

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();  
String qvalue = (String) b.get("quesNum"); //error line
```

however the problem got resolved using LocalBroadcastManager.

On Adaptor:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("ques");
 intent.putExtra("qn",quesNumb);

 LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

On Target Activity:

```
onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
 ...

 LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
            new IntentFilter("ques"));
  }

public BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

       String qvalue = intent.getStringExtra("qn");

        Toast.makeText(UserResponseListActivity.this,"Number"+qvalue ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
```

That worked But don't know why I was getting null-pointer exception for the first solution, which should also work, right? Any idea? @Raj

Comment: I think you are using an intent in a wrong way, There are many methods to send data via intent. One is direct passing, another is using bundle. You are combining both of these methods. Read documentation to have a clear approach among them. If still didn't work you can send me the code I will resolve it for you.

Comment: Actually the same code I used for other projects when activity also need to launch. Don't know the issue here. Well.. Yeah I will look that thing separately on a clean new project. BTW Thankyou very much for the support. :-)   Marking above as solution, just because it has less steps (adapter to target activity directly).   
    And thanks again for that useful post.

Answer (score 0):

So, you have to set onClickListener on your Recycler View. When user clicks an item pass its position and quesNum to main activity and pass them to another activity using an intent. Use interfaces to implement click listener on Recycler view.

In your adapter class, create interface to set on click listener and do:-

```
public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        public TextView tv;

        public Holder(View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);

            tv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    if(listener != null)
                    {
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();

                        if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION)
                        {
                            listener.onItemClicked(position, OTHER_VALUE);
                        }
                   }
                }
            }
        }
 }
```

and in your main Activity do:

```
public void onItemClicked(int position, String value)
    {
       // Toast.makeText(this, "You Clicked " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      //Create Intent Here

    }
```

Comment: So do I need to implement onclickListener on Adapter class? Again how I will pass data from adaptor to main activity. Will you hint through codes?